# ASP.NET Core handling JSON deserialization problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I would like to change default behavior of invalid JSON request handling in ASP.NET Core. I have this model:

```
public class Model
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

And when I send this request with this body

```
{
 "Id": null
}
```

It returns this error message:

```
 "Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Guid'. Path 'Id', line 2, position 11."
```

Of course this is absolutely logical but I want Id to be set to default value (Guid.Empty) instead of failing request. I have added this json config in Startup:

```
services.AddMvc()
            .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.Error = (a, e) =>
            {
                e.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
            })
```

Error handler is being hit however ASP.NET Core still returns failure. This in different behavior compared to ASP.NET Web API where this was possible.

Comment: The message is very clear: ```"Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Guid'. Path 'Id', line 2, position 11."```. Shouldn't your model be a nullable Guid such as ```Guid?``` instead?

Comment: Yes absolutely but what I am doing is update of old ASP.NET Web API app to ASP.NET Core. I would like to avoid such changes as it may have other consequences. Exactly this case (null -> Guid.Empty) works in Web API.

Comment: If you try to load the same json, with a console application for example, targeting different frameworks such as .NET 4.8.x and .NET Core 2.x what happens? are you sure the issue happens on the parsing by the asp.net core engine or by the json engine?

Comment: Problem is in JsonInputFormatter class in ASP.NET Core which has also its own error handler for this. Under the hood it use Newtonsoft JSON.NET for parsing and this handling with e.ErrorContext.Handled = true; works when it is not in ASP.NET core app

Comment: You can make a custom convert in the `AddJsonOptions`. Then each time that you see a `null` value you set `Guid.Empty`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have found, this behavior is handled by JsonInputFormatter, you could custom the formatter to override this behavior like

1. `IgnoreGuidErrorJsonInputFormatter`

   ```
   public class IgnoreGuidErrorJsonInputFormatter : JsonInputFormatter
   {
       public IgnoreGuidErrorJsonInputFormatter(ILogger logger, JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings, ArrayPool<char> charPool, ObjectPoolProvider objectPoolProvider, MvcOptions options, MvcJsonOptions jsonOptions) : base(logger, serializerSettings, charPool, objectPoolProvider, options, jsonOptions)
       {
           serializerSettings.Error = (a, e) =>
           {
               var errors = e.ErrorContext.Error;
               e.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
           };
       }
   }
   ```
2. Register `IgnoreGuidErrorJsonInputFormatter`

   ```
   services.AddMvc(options =>
   {
       var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
       var customJsonInputFormatter = new IgnoreGuidErrorJsonInputFormatter(
                   serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>().CreateLogger<IgnoreGuidErrorJsonInputFormatter>(),
                   serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MvcJsonOptions>>().Value.SerializerSettings,
                   serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ArrayPool<char>>(),
                   serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ObjectPoolProvider>(),
                   options,
                   serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MvcJsonOptions>>().Value
           );
       options.InputFormatters.Insert(0, customJsonInputFormatter);
   });
   ```

Comment: I have already fixed my problem with custom JsonConverter but this looks also as a solution, thanks!

Comment: You can implement a custom `IPostConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>` which registers your input formatter, to avoid building a service provider. FYI.