# Exception handling when invalid GUID is posted to API endpoint

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am using .net core 3.1. Below is a simple create user API endpiont.

```
[HttpPost("create-user")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAsync([FromBody] User newUser)
{
    var result = user_service.CreateUser(newUser);

    return result;
}

public class User : IUserAccountBase
{
    [JsonPropertyName("identification_guid")]
    public Guid? IdentificationGuid { get; set; }
    
    [JsonPropertyName("first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("last_name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I post to the above endpoint with the below body,

```
{
    "identification_guid": "test01",
    "first_name": "Homer",
    "last_name": "Simpson"
}
```

Below is the json exception that gets thrown back,

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-e86c1f983ece68448d4d5e3a7374b632-10e7410e4add0540-00",
    "errors": {
        "$.identification_guid": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Nullable`1[System.Guid]. Path: $.identification_guid | LineNumber: 1 | BytePositionInLine: 40."
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to custom handle this exception and return my own error message. Can you please suggest how this can be achieved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET Core handling JSON deserialization problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58018207/asp-net-core-handling-json-deserialization-problems)

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom attribute for this.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class GuidIdentifierAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
    {
        var identifierString = context.ObjectInstance?.ToString();

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(identifierString) && Guid.TryParse(identifierString, out _))
        {
            return new ValidationResult($"Please enter a valid {context.MemberName}!");
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class User : IUserAccountBase
{
    [GuidIdentifier]
    [JsonPropertyName("identification_guid")]
    public Guid? IdentificationGuid { get; set; }
    
    [JsonPropertyName("first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("last_name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```